# Got an exception while working with javax.sound.samples library....!

Tags: java, audio

Can anyone tell me where i have done mistake in this java program.
I always get an exception caught while i run this.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class x 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  try
  {
  File f=new File("mm.wav");
  AudioInputStream a=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
  AudioFormat audioFormat = a
                   .getFormat();
             DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                   Clip.class, audioFormat);
             Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem
                   .getLine(dataLineInfo);
             clip.open(a);
             clip.start();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("exception caught ");
 }
 }
}
```

It will throws this exception

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:351)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:135)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1111)
    at x.main(x.java:10)
```

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace , Or you want us to run this code :) ??

Comment: You need to at least post *what* exception is thrown, and the top dozen or so lines from the stack trace. Otherwise, you're not going to get much help.

Comment: java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
 at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:351)
 at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:135)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1111)
 at x.main(x.java:10)

Comment: I actually did take this code, compiled it on Mac OS X 10.6, using both Java 1.5 and Java 1.6, and ran it. It worked both times. I also tried it with an empty WAV file, just to see if that caused the exception. No luck; I got an EOFException, which makes sense. What JDK and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:

After testing your code, I get the same error every time I try to give your code an invalid sound file (I gave it text files and binary java class files :) ).  I got the same exception every time.  It's not a very user-friendly exception, but check the validity of your wav file.

EDIT #2:

If I change the code to:

```
  AudioInputStream a=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
      new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)));
```

then an invalid sound file will give the more pleasing exception:  `UnsupportedAudioFileException`

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled over the same issue, and dived into
javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
The code there asks providers whether they can handle the sound format, and catches UnsupportedAudioFileException to continue with next provider. Code comments state "throws IOException", and IOException happens when AudioSystem tries the provider
com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader
Yes, the provider throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, but before doing so it calls "reset()" on the input stream. I use package resources via standard URL.openStream(), the URL stream doesn't support reset(), and throws IOException just **before** SoftMidiAudioFileReader throws UnsupportedAudioFileException.

Bug in class AudioSystem: UnsupportedAudioFileException is catched, and continues with next provider, while the unnecessary IOException aborts all other providers.

Your stacktrace shows you stepped into the same bug.
Got no work around yet.