# Error trying to run .Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So I have had no problem running a .jar file in the past. And the .jar program has been running fine, playing music, displaying images etc.

But recently I added in another music file (of the same format as the rest of them in there and slightly smaller size) and now, when I export to a .jar file, the .jar file wont run correctly, it just displays a white form.

Any help would be awesome! :)

EDIT: I ran the file using the command prompt and this error came up:

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported                              
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)                      
at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)                              
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)                                                                              at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)          
at Audio.AudioPlayer.<init>(AudioPlayer.java:14)                                
at GameState.StateManager.<init>(StateManager.java:60)                          
at Main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:77)                                       
at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:82)                                        
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)                                 
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException                           
at GameState.StateManager.update(StateManager.java:174)                         
at Main.GamePanel.update(GamePanel.java:122)                                    
at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:93)                                        
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: How are you creating the JAR file?

Comment: In Eclipse File>Export>Runnable Jar File>Package Required Libraries..

Exactly how I have been doing it previously, and it has worked up til now.

Comment: The code is fine, it has worked up til now, but I added one more file, and it doesn't like it at all.. The file is in the exact same format as the rest of the other files. It runs in eclipse fine, it is only when I export it to a .jar file that it winges.

Answer (score 0):

The reset() function of InflaterInputStream is not implemented and **always** throws that Exception.

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html#reset--):

> The method reset for class InflaterInputStream does nothing except throw an IOException.

The real question is, why is SoftMidiAudioFileReader calling that method?

To find the answer, all I did was google "com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader" and the first result is a StackOverflow question about the same error: [Got an exception while working with javax.sound.samples library....!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556896/got-an-exception-while-working-with-javax-sound-samples-library)

It turns out this happens when you give the AudioPlayer an invalid sound file. Check to make sure the sound file is valid, because it's not.

Comment: Cheers, I will have a dig around.